# What is the importance of this number in The Magicians?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-magicians

In Season 4 Episode 10 Margo walked 359,965 steps after being banished from the Kingdom of Fillory.

What is the importance of this number?

What does this number suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Nothing

At least, nothing specific except a considerable distance (c200+ miles) especially as she has been walking for some time already.

Comment: what does c200+ miles means

Comment: c= *circa* which is latin for *approximately*.

Comment: what is the formula for conversion of steps into miles

Comment: http://www.thewalkingsite.com/10000steps.html but it depends on the person.

Comment: *"An average person has a stride length of approximately 2.1 to 2.5 feet. That means that it takes over 2,000 steps to walk one mile;"*